# Style overlay when toggle selected

Tags: javascript, navbar, overlay

I have a navbar and i am trying to add an overlay color when the hamburger toggle is selected.
The overlay class is outside of the nav when the hamburger select box is selected.
However, am not able to create a full page overlay when the hamburger check box is selected. Seems the overlay css styling cannot be accessed by the input checkbox because it is outside of the navbar. Would appreciate any suggestions on how to style an element outside of input select box such as a hamburger.

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .overlay{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:green;
  z-index:10000;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div><!--this should produce overlay over entire page when the toggler is selected-->

<div class="navbar">
   
  <!--toggle-->
  <input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu">
  <label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle"  >
    <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
    <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
    <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
  </label>

  <div id="sidebarMenu" class="sidebar">
    <ul class="sidebarMenuInner">
      <li><a href="https://vanila.io" target="_blank">Company</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://instagram.com/plavookac" target="_blank">Instagram</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/plavookac" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCDfZM0IK6RBgud8HYGFXAJg" target="_blank">YouTube</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/plavookac/" target="_blank">Linkedin</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .overlay` selects the child of a subsequent sibling of the input with class overlay ... your overlay is a previous sibling of the inputs parent - so your selector is completely wrong

Comment: you probably want `.overlay:has(~ .navbar > input[type=checkbox]:checked)`

Comment: Thanks Jaroma. Tried the code suggested but unfortunately this still isn't working to get the overlay  the body when the toggle is selected:( Am using:
 .overlay:has(~ .navbar > input[type=checkbox]:checked){
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:pink;
  z-index:10000;
}